# How to fit a two-term exponential in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I would like to fit a two-term exponential model to my data given as (x,y), i.e.

```
f(x) = a * exp(b * x) + c * exp(d * x)
```

In essence, I need to replicate Matlab's `exp2` model type in R calculated as

```
f = fit(x, y, 'expo')
```

Comment: Do you have any data sample to show? Is `x` negative? Is `y` negative?

Comment: @Benjamin - just to clarify, `?nls` is a function included with R by default

Comment: You've listed the nls function (stats package), which is a good place to start. Have a look at the documentation, and show us what you'e tried. See http://robinlovelace.net/2013/10/23/nls-demonstation.html for a few hints.

Comment: You should encourage people to submit data so they have a MWE. I'll edit the question to remove the extraneous material.

Comment: @42-: I agree, that's exactly what Severin Pappadeux and I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/singular-gradient-error-in-nls-with-correct-starting-values) does a good job explaining how to fit an abstract model like that. The jist of it is- use `nls()` to fit a "Nonlinear Least Squares" model:

```
# Using the mpg data in ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
# Create list of initial estimates
insertList = list(a=1,b=-0.01,c=1,d=-0.01)
# fit model
m1 = nls(displ ~ a*exp(b*cty) + c*exp(d*cyl),data =mpg, start = insertList)
```

and the function *should* do the rest...

The hard part is finding estimates to your model that will not give you an error when inputting this. The link provides insight into this. Good luck!

Edit: Made the changes @Ben Bolker suggested; also, didn't realize mpg was in ggplot2 and not base R, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You might want to define the variable before you use it... and explain how to get to mpg.

Comment: `mpg` is in the `ggplot2` package, not in base R.   And it would be better to use `m1 = nls(displ ~ a*exp(b*cty) + c*exp(d*cyl),data =mpg,  ...)`

Comment: ... and try `insertList = list(a=1,b=-0.01,c=1,d=-0.01)` for starting conditions that *do* work ...